# Procedural frosting texture

Tags: texturing, procedural

What do you believe is the best way to make a procedural texture like the one on the photo? I mean the top part. I tried to combine noise and voronoi/musgrave, but it didn`t give the desired amount of tiny bumps and air pockets.

Thanks. 
[image]

Comment: Instead of a procedural texture would it not be better to create a curve that follows the path of the piped frosting and then use the Extrude Bevel Shape with another curve that defines a cross section of the frosting (many pointed star shape). Once you have the basic Mesh modelled then you can texture with a displacement modifier.

Comment: "Tiny bumps and air pockets", this doesn't sound like the current answer. Could you clarify which part of the object you want to create, possibly marking it in the image?

Comment: Thanks everyone, please see the new photo, I show there what I need exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a **Bezier Circle** (Add/Curve) <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit* mode and from the **Specials** menu <kbd>w</kbd> **Subdivide** the circle twice. Deselect all the control points <kbd>a</kbd> then select every other one by holding down <kbd>shift</kbd>.

Move the selected control points up (<kbd>g</kbd> and then <kbd>z</kbd> to constrain to Z axis) then from the **Top** view <kbd>NUMPAD 7</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> to rotate.

[image: Basic path of icing curve on mesh cake]

<kbd>Tab</kbd> out of Edit mode and add another Bezier Circle and name it "*Bevel Profile*".

Go into the **Curve properties** of the original Bezier Circle and increase the **Extrude** value and set the **Bevel Object** to be "*Bevel Profile*".
[image: Piped icing with no profile]

This shows what we are trying to do and you can edit the "*Bevel Profile*". **Subdivide** and this time <kbd>s</kbd> scale the alternate control points to make a star shape.
[image: Piped icing with Star profile]

And finally you can add some materials, duplicate, scale etc.
[image: Basic cake mesh with two lots of piped icing]